# JavaScript Game, How change the key that gives the action

Tags: javascript, html

I use the Game here https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_default_gravity and in this version the key to accelerate is
left click mouse and I want and try to make spacebar work to accelerate, by using keycode("32") but I don't know where to place this line and how to write it.

The code I try is there:
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/9w8TniLjKcOLlabq?open=lib%2Fscript.js

What I expect is that I can accelerate by pressing spacebar ("32").
But for now, it's working just with mouse left clicking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Not sure what you were trying to do with `while.keyup` but all you need is

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 32) {
    accelerate(-0.2)
  }
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 32) {
    accelerate(0.05)
  }
});
```

You're also going to want to prevent scrolling with the spacebar, this can be done by adding `event.preventDefault();` and also checking to make sure `event.target == document.body`

Working snippet:

```js
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;

function startGame() {
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
  myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
  myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
  myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  this.type = type;
  this.score = 0;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.gravity = 0;
  this.gravitySpeed = 0;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    if (this.type == "text") {
      ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
  }
  this.newPos = function() {
    this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
    this.hitBottom();
  }
  this.hitBottom = function() {
    var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
    if (this.y > rockbottom) {
      this.y = rockbottom;
      this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    }
  }
  this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
  for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
    if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
      return;
    }
  }
  myGameArea.clear();
  myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
  if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
    x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
    minHeight = 20;
    maxHeight = 200;
    height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxHeight - minHeight + 1) + minHeight);
    minGap = 50;
    maxGap = 200;
    gap = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxGap - minGap + 1) + minGap);
    myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
    myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
    myObstacles[i].x += -1;
    myObstacles[i].update();
  }
  myScore.text = "SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
  myScore.update();
  myGamePiece.newPos();
  myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
  if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
  myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 32 && event.target == document.body) {
    accelerate(-0.2)
    event.preventDefault();

  }
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 32 && event.target == document.body) {
    accelerate(0.05)
    event.preventDefault();


  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="startGame()">
  <br>
  <button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
  <p>Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air</p>
  <p>How long can you stay alive?</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where do I put ? event.preventDefault(); and event.target == document.body

Comment: It's already in my edited snippet at the bottom.  Where you check for the key code you're also checking for `event.target == document.body`. The `event.preventDefault()` is inside those 
`addEventListener` functions.

Comment: Yes, I see, Thanks for your time and have a great day.